# Replace "Double Backslash" with a single backslash using sed?

Tags: sed, backslash

How can I replace a string containing double backslash with single backslash using sed?

for example:

Orignal:  `a\\b\\c`

Result:    `a\b\c`

Comment: I just tried something:

 echo "a\\b\\c" | sed "s/\\///g"

This work, but the following string doesnt do the replacement

{"photo_id": 1623397, "upload_time": "2005-03-11 19:49:21", "category_code": "A36", "media_code": "SIN", "credit": "ZZZ", "keywords": "地產(PROPERTY)", "spec_instr": null, "caption": "A\\"B\\"C。 C攝(Pix By : C) 20050311 地產", "object_name": null, "caption_is": "A\\"B\\"C。}

Comment: Perhaps `s/\\\\/\\/g' file`?